# Magento 2 : Set current store throughout the site

Tags: magento2, store-view, magento2.3.2, store-id, geoip

I want to set currentstore according to geoip of customer.for that i have tried below code:

> MagentoDir/app/code/Shasha/Geoip/Observer/Redirect.php

```
<?php 

namespace Shasha\Geoip\Observer;

class Redirect implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{

    protected $_objectManager;

    protected $_storeManager;

    protected $_curl;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseFactory
     */
    private $responseFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface
     */
    private $_urlInterface;

    protected $_session;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Framework\HTTP\Client\Curl $curl,
        \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseFactory $responseFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $urlInterface,
        \Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManagerInterface $session
    ) {
        $this->_objectManager  = $objectManager;
        $this->_storeManager   = $storeManager;
        $this->_curl           = $curl;
        $this->responseFactory = $responseFactory;
        $this->_urlInterface   = $urlInterface;
        $this->_session        = $session;
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $isChangeStore    = $this->_session->getCustomRedirection();
        if(!($isChangeStore)){
            $visitorIp    = $this->getVisitorIp();
            $visitorIp        = '158.69.121.179';  // for canada
            $apiUrl       = "http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp?ip=".$visitorIp;
            $this->_curl->get($apiUrl);
            $response     = json_decode($this->_curl->getBody(), true);
            $countryCode  = $response['geoplugin_countryCode'];

            if($countryCode != null && $countryCode == 'CA'){
                $this->_session->setCustomRedirection(true);
                $this->_storeManager->setCurrentStore(2);

            }
        }
    }

    function getVisitorIp()
    {
        $remoteAddress = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Framework\HTTP\PhpEnvironment\RemoteAddress');
        return $remoteAddress->getRemoteAddress();
    }

}
```

but unfortunately it not works throughout the site it only change on the home page. now i am stuck how can i proceed?

Any helps??

Thanks in advance..!!!